# Remove extra icons on startup

Tags: macos

I used to have two iMacs running Lion connected to each other via Firewire.

On starting up a computer, two icons representing both computers would appear. I would select one and type in the password.

Now I have sold one of the computers but both icons still appear on start-up, requiring me to choose one.

How do I eliminate the unnecessary start-up icon?

Comment: I don't think posting your e-mail address is necessary, you *can* click something about e-mail alerts for answers.

Comment: Could you possibly take a picture of the selection screen?

Comment: Yes please post a picture - I'm quite curious as to how you were "selecting a machine" as opposed to just booting one iMac and connecting to the other one via Firewire Target Disk Mode.

Comment: Or do you have two bootable partitions (Bootcamp maybe) on your Mac?